# Equivalent of toBuffer on the browser?

Tags: anchor

I have a node.js app where I succeed to convert an anchor BN to buffer but it does not works on the browser, it looks like I have to use something else.

- Works on node.js but not on the browser:

```
new anchor.BN(0).toBuffer("le", 2)
```

- error received:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).toBuffer is not a function
```

Do you know the equivalent that works in a react app ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to convert from BN to Buffer using `toArrayLike`

```
new anchor.BN(0).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 2),
```